# jQuery foreach Obj

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function that get's all the data in my database...

however when I tried to do a `.each` function it says that `result.each` is not a function.

here's my code.

**result of my Ajax:**

```
[
{"UnitID":"1","Description":"sample1","Status":"1"},   
{"UnitID":"2","Description":"sample 2","Status":"1"}
]
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
function PopulateTable(table){
var $this = $(table);
var $url = $this.data('url');
 $.ajax({
    url: $url,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        result.each(function(k, v){
        console.log(k + " " + v);
        });
    }
 });
}
```

dunno what's wrong with it..
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

jQuery defines `.each()` twice for different uses:

- The [`.each()` method](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is just available to `jQuery` element collections.
- The [`jQuery.each()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) however can be used with any collection or object.

Since `result` is an `Array`, you'll want to use the latter form to iterate, providing it as an argument:

```
success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    jQuery.each(result, function(k, v){
        console.log(k + " " + v);
    });
}
```

---

Side note: If you're seeing `[object Object]` in the log...

`v` in each of the iterations will refer to one of the objects within the array and the above string is the default output given when converting an object to a string, as `+` will do for you.

To show information from the object, you can access its properties:

```
jQuery.each(result, function (k, v) {
    console.log(k + ' ' + v.UnitID + ' ' + v.Description);
});
```

Also, in many environments/browsers when you provide an object as a separate argument, the console will either auto-format all of its contents or display it as an interactive tree menu:

```
console.log(k, v);
```

Comment: Good answer! OP should try this first :}

Comment: @SetSailMedia I did this.. do I need a nested loop?